# Refine Blog post by category in Bigcommerce blog

Tags: blogs, categories, bigcommerce

I need some help today.

When we add any blog post to Bigcommerce default blog, do we have any option to assign blog category?

or how we can create a Blog category? I can't see any option for this as well and after contacting Support they haven't been fair to issue and said to ask this in forum.

Actually I want to add refine post by Category in blog page so I need to add category but at the moment it seems i do not have any option to add category.

also I tried it with tags that we add in blog post but there isn't any way to get all the tags list that we added in various posts.

can you guys please help me out for this issue?

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: This is no blog category functionality. This is a better question for tech support than stackoverflow.

Comment: To be honest, I asked the same to support but they reverted me is ugly.

They said I can take help from their Partners and take services from their partners.

Comment: BTW @Alyss Thank you for your response.